# Question about Cartan involution on wikipedia

Tags: lie-algebras

I am a beginner in representation theory.
I have some questions about Cartan involution.
The following is the link  in wikipedia

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_involution

My question is about $\mathfrak{su}(n)$.
If $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ is the Lie algebra of compact semisimple group,
the only Cartan involution is $\theta_0:X\mapsto X$.
So why $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$ and $\theta_3$ are there?
In what situation are they available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These maps $\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3$ are involutions in the sense that they are self-inverse Lie algebra automorphisms of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$. They aren't Cartan involutions because the associated bilinear form $B_\theta$ isn't positive definite.

Comment: So, they are examples of involutions of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ which are not Cartan involutions. I understand, thanks a lot !